# Is it possible to have a ↓ b = b ↓ a ? Explain why a ↓ c = a ↓ (b ↓ c

Tags: calculus, vectors, applications

Can anyone explain in which cases do the follow occur? Preferably with diagrams as well?

1. Is it possible to have a ↓ b = b ↓ a ?
2. Explain why a ↓ c = a ↓ (b ↓ c )

   a ↓ b means a's projection on b.

Comment: Could you explain your notation? What do you mean by a ↓ b?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a standard or widely used symbol. Explain.

Comment: vector a's projection onto vector b

Comment: For 2 you also need to assume that b and c are not orthogonal, i.e. b ↓ c $\ne 0$, so that vector projection can be well-defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. if $\mathbf a = \mathbf b$, of course the projection of vector $\mathbf a$ onto the line spanned by $\mathbf b = \mathbf a$ is $\mathbf a$, and conversly.
2. If you know the dot product, observe that
   $$\mathbf a \downarrow \mathbf b = \frac{\langle \mathbf a\cdot \mathbf b\rangle}{\langle \mathbf b\cdot \mathbf b\rangle}\mathbf b$$.

Thus, \begin{align}
\mathbf a \downarrow ( \mathbf b \downarrow \mathbf  c ) &= \mathbf a \downarrow \left( \frac{\langle \mathbf b\cdot \mathbf c\rangle}{\langle \mathbf c\cdot \mathbf c\rangle}\mathbf c \right)
\end{align}

Let $h = \frac{\langle \mathbf b\cdot \mathbf c\rangle}{\langle \mathbf c\cdot \mathbf c\rangle}$.  Of course the line spanned by $\mathbf c$ and $h \cdot \mathbf c$ is the same, and that should hint you that the projection should give you the same resul.  Indeed we have

$$
\mathbf a \downarrow ( \mathbf b \downarrow \mathbf c )
= \mathbf a \downarrow \left( h \cdot \mathbf c \right)
= \frac{\langle \mathbf a\cdot h \cdot \mathbf c\rangle}{\langle h \cdot \mathbf c\cdot h \cdot \mathbf c\rangle} h \cdot \mathbf c
= \frac{h^2 \langle \mathbf a\cdot \mathbf c\rangle}{h^2\langle \mathbf c\cdot\mathbf c\rangle}\mathbf c
= \frac{\langle \mathbf a\cdot \mathbf c\rangle}{\langle \mathbf c\cdot \mathbf c\rangle}\mathbf c
= \mathbf a \downarrow \mathbf c.
$$